# MongoDB TTL does not work on atlas but works fine on localhost

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, ttl

I followed this article - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/
I created the index on atlas first. It was added successfully. But the documents weren't deleted as per expiry.
I used the same method on localhost mongo shell, and it worked fine.

I added this index

```
{ "expiresAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 }
```

where expiresAt is a Date object in my document.

This is the document I expected to be deleted.

```
_id    :5f55f440058cdd3754907255
name    :"first"
language    :"Plain Text"
content    :"Some text"
createdAt    :2020-09-07T08:50:08.708+00:00
expiresAt    :2020-09-07T08:51:08.709+00:00
__v    :0
```

Comment: Share the doc which you expect to be deleted i.e date value especially?

Comment: @Gibbs I have now added the doc to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question on mongodb forums.
Pavel_Duchovny was very patient and helpful. He answered [here](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-ttl-does-not-work-on-atlas-but-works-fine-on-localhost/8896/10).

So while using the web UI -
You need to place field name under FIELDS:
`{ "expiresAt": 1 }`

And under OPTIONS:
`{ expireAfterSeconds: 0 }`